# Nginx request not being logged

Tags: nginx, ssl, timeout

I'm somewhat new to nginx and I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue.   I have a website that I can access through https no problem.  However, when I try to access it from a different network it does not work.  I get a "This site cannot be reached error message"
This might be a network issue however, I can ping the server no problem and telnet to ports 80 and 443 without issues.
While on the nginx server I used tcpdump to see if the connection is making all the way to the server and it is.  I compared the tcpdump with a location that works and it seems like the web server is receiving an empty string from the location that does not work.
I see nothing relevant under the error.log file even if I turn the logging level to debug.
The access.log file only records attempts from the location that works.

I read online that there is a way to get access.log data from an empty request, however this is not working for me.  When I restart nginx it fails to start.
Here is the link I found this information:
[nginx access logs ignore certain requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/45353/nginx-access-logs-ignore-certain-requests)

I'm thinking that if I can log the request it will give me a better idea of what is going on.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

**TCP DUMP
HTTPS request is never recognized by NGINXs**

```
07:28:10.232407 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [S], seq 1918828503, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale8,nop,nop,sackOK],**length 0**
07:28:10.232458 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053: Flags [S.], seq 1433909711, ack 1918828504, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
07:28:10.232483 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [S], seq 1331643201, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
07:28:10.232531 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054: Flags [S.], seq 2346320018, ack 1331643202, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
07:28:10.232817 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2053, length 0
07:28:10.232848 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2053, length 0
07:28:10.232977 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:218, ack 1, win 2053, length 217
07:28:10.233003 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054: Flags [.], ack 218, win 237, length 0
07:28:10.233056 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:218, ack 1, win 2053, length 217
07:28:10.233076 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053: Flags [.], ack 218, win 237, length 0
07:28:10.236559 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054: Flags [P.], seq 1:5591, ack 218, win 237, length 5590
07:28:10.236885 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2053, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {4381:5591}], length 0
07:28:10.236915 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63054: Flags [.], seq 1:1461, ack 218, win 237, length 1460
07:28:10.238628 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053: Flags [P.], seq 1:5591, ack 218, win 237, length 5590
07:28:10.238961 IP 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2053, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {4381:5591}], length 0
07:28:10.238994 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053: Flags [.], seq 1:1461, ack 218, win 237, length 1460
07:28:10.439523 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.XX.XXX.XXX.63053: Flags [.], seq 1:1461, ack 218, win 237, length 1460
```

**HTTPS request works without issues**

```
09:08:13.088028 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [P.], seq 116250704:116251547, ack 1890870853, win 512, **length 843**
09:08:13.088065 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031: Flags [.], ack 843, win 311, length 0
09:08:13.088071 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [P.], seq 843:889, ack 1, win 512, length 46
09:08:13.088078 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031: Flags [.], ack 889, win 311, length 0
09:08:13.088359 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031: Flags [P.], seq 1:47, ack 889, win 311, length 46
09:08:13.092010 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031: Flags [P.], seq 47:2210, ack 889, win 311, length 2163
09:08:13.146358 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 47, win 16383, length 0
09:08:13.168708 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 47, win 16383, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {1413:2210}], length 0
09:08:13.194117 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 47, win 16384, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {1413:2210}], length 0
09:08:13.281878 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 2210, win 16375, length 0
09:08:13.311027 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 2210, win 16384, length 0
09:08:13.342792 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [P.], seq 889:985, ack 2210, win 16384, length 96
09:08:13.344140 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031: Flags [P.], seq 2210:2994, ack 985, win 311, length 784
09:08:13.410820 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 2994, win 16380, length 0
09:08:13.448558 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 2994, win 16384, length 0
09:08:18.404894 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [P.], seq 985:1826, ack 2994, win 509, length 841
09:08:18.430867 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031: Flags [P.], seq 2994:5158, ack 1826, win 329, length 2164
09:08:18.514749 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 2994, win 16384, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {4360:5158}], length 0
09:08:18.514775 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 5158, win 16384, length 0
09:08:18.543209 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [P.], seq 1826:2061, ack 5158, win 16384, length 235
09:08:18.544684 IP mira-lb.local.https > 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031: Flags [P.], seq 5158:5942, ack 2061, win 347, length 784
09:08:18.613012 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 5942, win 16380, length 0
09:08:18.657856 IP 10.AA.AAA.AAA.56031 > mira-lb.local.https: Flags [.], ack 5942, win 16384, length 0
```

Comment: Please provide relevant details: the name and global IP address of your web site; the network from which you tried to access it, and any additional error messages you may have omitted.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the reply.  The web server is in an internal network nated to another internal network so there is no IP address that anyone else can access.  There are no errors but I can paste the tcpdump if you think it's helpful

Comment: Yes, the tcpdump output would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I added the TCP dump and highlighted the initial request lengths

Comment: Something is going on in the network or at the client end of that connection. You can see the client is retransmitting a lot, which indicates that it is not consistently receiving data back from the web server. You should investigate from that end.

Comment: I'm looking for proof to my network engineer that there is a networking issues, so thank you Michael.

Comment: Your network engineer will probably want a tcpdump in pcap format, i.e. `-w file.pcap`.